# QtWebEngineWidgets Save Image to file

Tags: python, pyqt5

Hi I have a browser in my Python PyQt5 App e.g. `browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()` I now would like to open e.g. google.com right click the Google Image and select Save image.
How can I implement the Save image action from the Context menu? I also would like to controle in my code where the Image gets saved.
Copy image and Copy image address somehow work by default but not Save image or Save page.
Extracting the Image src from html and using something like `urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgURL)` is not an option.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [QWebEngineProfile.downloadRequested()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html#downloadRequested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tank you ekhumoro!
`QWebEngineProfile.downloadRequested()` was the way to go.

some code if someone has the same problem:

add `download_requested = QtCorePySide6.Signal(QWebEngineDownloadRequest)` in class
add downloadRequested to QWebEngineView `browser.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(self._download_requested)`

provide a callback function:

```
def _download_requested(self, item):
    ...
    item.setDownloadDirectory(directory)
    item.setDownloadFileName(fileName)
    item.accept()
```